# Error: Object Reference is not set to an instance of object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently developing an application that will give user capability of downloading demo software from link provided by us in his email address. After 24 hours, now I have done through link shown in his email address, and he can  download but in the coding of disable of this link .. I'm getting error    my code is ..

```
protected void btn_sub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    cn.Open();
    objInquiry.Name = txt_name.Text.ToString().Trim();
    objInquiry.MobileNo = txtMobileNo.Text.ToString().Trim();
    objInquiry.EmailId = txt_eid.Text.ToString().Trim();
    objInquiry.InquiryFor = "Agriculture Product Marketing comity System".ToString().Trim();
    objInquiry.Message = txt_msg.Text.ToString().Trim();

    using (DataSet ds = objInquiry.InsertInquiry())
    {
        Msg.Visible = true;
        Msg.Text = "Thank U For Inquiry We Will Send Demo Link To Your Email Please Check Your Email Regularly";
    }

    try
    {
        DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["period"].ToString());
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan ts = dt2 - dt1;

        if (ts.TotalMinutes > 5)
        {
            Response.Write("Download time is over");
        }
        else
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add(txt_eid.Text);
            mail.Subject = txtInquiryFor.Text;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = "Welcome Mr." + txt_name.Text + "<br><br>";
            mail.Body += "To ShreeHans Webnology" + "<br><br>";
            mail.Body += "Thank u for putting inquiry for" + txtInquiryFor.Text + "<br><br>";
            mail.Body += "Please Click on Following Link To Download Your Demo" + "<br><br>";
            mail.Body += "<a href=\"http://www.test.co.in/ConatctUs.aspx?period=" + DateTime.Now + "'\">Download Demo Software</a>";

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "*****");
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: can you put here the error message you get?

Comment: DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["period"].ToString());

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: ex.ToString should give you enough information..

Comment: And yet again, Definitive answer: [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net/4660186#4660186).

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned that the error is in the line

```
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["period"].ToString());
```

So it suggest that you have null value in

```
Request.QueryString["period"].ToString()
```

First check for null value then convert it to date time

```
if(Request.QueryString["period"]!=null)
{
    DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["period"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably `Request.QueryString["period"]` is null so when calling `ToString()` on it, you would get the Object Reference not set to an instance of an object exception.

Check for a null reference before calling `ToString`:

```
var period = Request.QueryString["period"];
if (period != null) {
    DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(period.ToString());
}
```

Comment: so what should be the  solution how i can  fill that null value ?

Comment: Since it's the querystring, that value should be in your url: `/index.html?period=whatever`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if that parameter is there in your QueryString.

```
TimeSpan ts;
if(null != Request.QueryString["period"])
{
  DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["period"].ToString());
  DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
  TimeSpan ts = dt2 - dt1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["period"].ToString())` is throwing error then than means you don't have `period` in your querystring. Better to check

```
if(Request.QueryString["period"]!=null)
{
  DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["period"].ToString());
 . .
 . .
}
```